# How to send email in cakephp 3.6.7..?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.2, cakephp-3.4, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.3

I am using cakephp3.6.7 while configuring app.php it will show error.

Error:

```
Could not send email: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25,
verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions

1. The connection to your mailserver in your php.ini is not pointing to the correct SMTP server: Make sure that SMTP host and port are pointing to your actual mailserver.
2. The configuration is correct but there is no SMTP server running on localhost:25: Make sure, that there is a mailserver running on your local machine on port 25.